# Bit confused with cloudfront and why my cert for the CNAME is not working

Tags: ssl, amazon-cloudfront

I am getting this message on my main site, after I setup a CloudFront distribution. I created a certificate for `cdn.example.com`, chose custom and entered `cdn.example.com` for use with HTTPS.

I created a `CNAME` in my DNS configuration for `cdn.example.com`, and I added the validation record as requested by AWS. The certificate shows up as issued and validated.

```
    Failed to load resource: The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “cdn.example.com”, which could put your confidential information at risk.
```

No images get loaded and the site does not render as it should. If I use the cloudfront url (i.e. d12345.cloudfront.net), all works fine. Do I need to add a SAN to my certificate, such as the main domain (i.e. `example.com`) in addition to `cdn.example.com`? If so, how does that work as I already use a SSL certificate for my `www.example.com` and `example.com` from *Let's Encrypt*.

I am using WordPress and wpfastestcache to integrate CloudFront with the website, where I specified `cdn.example.com` and the origin as `example.com`.

Comment: Can you provide the actual domain name?  This is not a problem with an obvious explanation and it would be helpful to examine the certificate CloudFront is using.

Comment: hi Michael, its' grabaguru.com.

Comment: Looking at what is happening, I don't believe your ACM certificate is actually attached to your CloudFront distribution. Check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesSSLCertificate ... you want "Custom SSL Certificate" and "Only Clients that Support Server Name Indication (SNI)" selected, and the ACM cert chosen here.

Comment: I just had another look and it seemed i used the default cloudfront ssl certificate. I guess was in the middle of requesting a SSL cert in the certstore and had left it at that while waiting for it to validate, and never bothered to put it to custom again. Thanks for your assistance Michael, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This question was confusing, since it seemed to describe a very unlikely condition.  How could a newly-configured CloudFront distribution with a new certificate from ACM offer an invalid certificate?

In truth, I was distracted by part of the "helpful" browser error message,  *"You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be..."* I mistakenly assumed that this implied that the hostname in the certificate was correct ("pretending to be") but that the certificate was invalid for some other reason.

As it turns out, the certificate being offered was the default, generic `*.cloudfront.net` certificate, so the hostname in the cert didn't match the custom domain name.

After creating a certificate in ACM, it needs to be associated with the CloudFront distribution, as mentioned at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesSSLCertificate.

Another hint to the nature of the problem would have been observable in the ACM console.  There, the certificate would have shown `In Use? No`.

> **In Use?** – Whether the ACM Certificate is actively associated with an AWS service such as Elastic Load Balancing or CloudFront. The value can be **No** or **Yes**.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-list.html#gs-acm-list-console

Comment: can't say using cloudfront has really improved the speed of my site (although it has increased my scores on gtmetrix). Pretty sure using without was at last a second faster. Maybe i need to wait for a while ?